# How to animate enlargement of a UISearchBar to the left side in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

> I want to:
>
> 1. Grow a UISearchBar to the left 93 pixels
> 2. Maintain it docked to the right
> 3. Do a soft animation while enlarging the view **only** to the left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This is how to overcome enlargement just to the **Left** side in **swift**

> (This code will enlarge/shrinks the searchBar **93** pixels over the left side when user start/end editing)

---

1. **SharedNavigationbBar** is the UIView that implements the **UISearchBarDelegate**
2. **searchBarWidth** is an outlet to a constrain holding the width of the UISearchBar

---

3. An autolayout constrain **must** exists on your storyboard or nib file to allow resizing into the left side.
   In this case, the neighbord left component is an **UIButton**.

---

[image]
  [image]

---

4. Add the following code as an extension or inside your class to perform the animated resizing.

---

```
extension SharedNavigationBar: UISearchBarDelegate
{
//amount of pixels to enlarge to the left
 private var offsetSearchBarLeft:CGFloat
    {
    get {
        return 93
    }
 }

///Enlarges search bar
 func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

   self.animateSearchBar(self.searchBar, enlarge: true)
 }

///Shrinks search bar
 func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

   self.animateSearchBar(self.searchBar, enlarge: false)
 }

//shrinks or enlarge the searchbar (this will be the function to call inside the animation)
 private func animateSearchBar(searchBar:UISearchBar, enlarge:Bool)
 {
     ///Important here, for this to work, the option and the searchbar size must be handled this way
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.LayoutSubviews, animations: { [weak self] () -> Void in

    let multiplier: CGFloat = enlarge ? 1 : -1

    let origin = searchBar.frame.origin.x + self!.offsetSearchBarLeft * multiplier
    let width = searchBar.frame.width + self!.offsetSearchBarLeft * multiplier

    //This Block of code, setting the new frame, needs to be inside the animation in order to work
    var newBounds:CGRect  = searchBar.frame;
    newBounds.origin.x = origin
    newBounds.size.width = width

    //Sets the new frame
    self?.searchBarWidth.constant = width
    searchBar.frame = newBounds

   }, completion: nil)
 }

}
```